# Microsoft graph API: unauthorized error when used with sharepoint and token attached

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a Sharepoint application. For my application, I have to fetch my details from Azure AD using Microsoft graph endpoints. I have generated the access token using `/token` endpoint and `client_credentials` grant type. When I use the token received in the response with the graph `/users` endpoint, I am getting an unauthorized error as shown in the below image:

[image]

On azure portal, all permissions are granted to microsoft graph API. Is there any configuration that is missing? How can I solve this unauthorized error?

Comment: How did you generate the access token? Could you provide more details?

Comment: I have followed this documentation to get access token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not test with a v2.0 endpoint, if it is acceptable to use a v1.0 endpoint, you could refer to the steps.

1.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> `New application registration`, more details see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app).

2.Go to the AD App -> `Keys` -> generate a key for the AD App, copy the key value.

3.Then go to the `Required permissions` -> `Add` -> select the `Microsoft Graph` and  `Read all users' full profiles` in the `APPLICATION PERMISSIONS` -> `Save` , **note** then don't forget to click the `Grant permissions` button.

[image]

4.I test it in the postman, specific the body what we need to get the `access_token`, the 
`client_id` is the `Application ID` of the AD App, `client_secret` is the `key vaule` you copied, `grant_type` is `client_credentials`, `resource` is `https://graph.microsoft.com/`.

Sample:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant ID>/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
```

[image]

5.Use the `access_token` to call MS Graph API, in my sample, I call the [`List users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) api, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I tried the above process, however error is still the same

Comment: @DishaAgrawal Decode your token in https://jwt.io/ , and give me the result screenshot.

Comment: @DishaAgrawal By the way, did you make sure you have successfully `Grant permissions`? it needs a global admin account consent.

Comment: There were mistakes in my request body and corresponding URL.Your answer was close but not exact

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the right scope in the token to use the "User" Endpoint.
Possible Scopes are:

- User.ReadBasic.All
- User.Read
- User.ReadWrite
- User.Read.All
- User.ReadWrite.All

For further detail pls look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Have you seen `On azure portal, all permissions are granted to microsoft graph API` in the question?

Comment: yes. But I think that the Token doesn't grant the rights to use the endpoint. As long as the token doesn't require those it shouldn't be possible to access it if I'm not mistaken. If I am I gladly take down my response =)

Comment: @Joy all permissions are granted to microsoft graph api